# Close serviceNow change using Rest Api

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

Is there a way to close the serviceNow change request using restApi ?

Have tried it using API Patch

Patch sn_chg_rest/change/{sys_id}

Body: {
“state”: “Closed”,
“close_code”: “***”
“close_notes”: “***”

It simply returns the list of fields as response. Status of the change is not changed.

Expecting the status of the change to be closed

Answer (score 2):

the state value should be the close state value expected by Servicenow api e.g. 3 for close and 4 for cancel
Also, per documentation depending on the type of the Change request i.e. Standard, Normal or Emergency, a Change can only move to 'Closed' from a certain state. A change can always move to 'Canceled' if it's not closed.

```
{
"state": "3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Field names are case sensitive. The correct field name is "state", not "State".

Comment: Thanks @giles3, must be a typo while typing it here. Have edited it. Please take a look. 
It’s not changing the state when given with state, close_code, close_notes